# What is the code for a calendar widget that looks like the below and can go by monthly/quarterly dates (not specific day)

Tags: html, image, calendar, widget

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGSd5.png)

I want the widget to look like the Event list+ above & to have configurable dates. What would the HTML script be?

I would like the image date to show June for example or Q1 not DD/MM/YYYY.

I cannot get a script to work.

Comment: your question is poorly asked.  What have you tried? your image is not clear so really don't know what you're asking.